# Approach to solve delimited scheduling

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, scheduling

I'm facing a problem and Im having problems to decide/figure-out an approach to solve it. The problem is the following:

> Given N phone calls to be made, schedule in a way that the maximum of them be made.

Know Info:

Number of phone calls pending

Number callers (people who will talk on the phone)

Type of phone call (Reminder, billing, negotiation, etc...)

Estimate duration of phone call type (reminder:1min, billing:3min, negotiation:15min, etc...)

Number of phone calls pending

Ideal date for a given call

"Minimum" date of the a given call (can't happen before...)

"Maximum" date of the a given call (can't happen after...)

A day only have 8 hours

Rules:

Phone calls cannot be made before the "Minimum" or after the "Maximum" date

Reminder call placed award 1 point, reminder call missed -2 points

Billing call placed award 6 points, billing call missed -9 points

Negotiation call placed award 20 points, Negotiation call missed -25 points

A phone calls to John must be placed by the first person to ever call him. Notice that it does not HAVE TO, but, that call will earn extra points if you do...

I know a little about A.I. and I can recognize this a problem that fits the class, but i just dont know which approach to take... should i use neural networks? Graph search?

PS: this is not a academic question. This a real world problem that im facing.
PS2: Pointing system is still being created... the points here sampled are not the real ones...
PS3: The resulting algol can be executed several times (batch job style) or it can be resolved online depending on the performance...
**PS4**: My contract states that I will charge the client based on: (amount of calls I place) + (ratio * the duration of the call), but theres a clause about quality of service, and only placing reminders calls is not good for me, because even when reminded, people still forget to attend their appointments... which reduces the "quality" of the service I provide... i dont know yet the exact numbers

Comment: "Extra points if you do" - is this homework?

Comment: @Dan-o no its not! (read last line) it's just a remark...

Comment: Ah.  I commented before reading to the end.  I am working on patience. :)

Comment: I think you need to edit your goal too - points don't matter if you're scheduling for maximum calls.  They do if you're scheduling for maximum points.

Comment: @Bobson i just edited again... check the ps4

Comment: I don't think it's possible to solve for an abstract "quality" score.  You'd need to just factor that into the point system and solve for the most points.  If placing entirely reminder calls can earn you 1 point a minute for 8 hours (480 points), but placing entirely negotiation calls can earn you an average of 2 points a minute, you'd optimize towards the latter.  But if *missing* a reminder call hurt about as much as making a negotiation call helped, it'd move towards an equilibrium.  Choosing the correct point values is critical for something like this.  Run **lots** of tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>This does not seem like a problem for AI.</strike>

If it were me I would create a set of rules, ordered by priority.  Then start filling in the caller's schedule.

Mabey one of the rules is to assign the shortest duration call types first (to satisfy the "maximum number of calls made" criteria).

This is sounding more and more like a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), where you would substitute in call duration and call points for weight and price.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a very basic answer, but you could try to "brute force" an optimum solution:

- Use the [Combinatorics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) library (it's in NuGet too) to generate every permutation of calls for a given person to make in a given time period (looking one week into the future, for instance).
- For each permutation, group the calls into 8-hour chunks by estimated duration, and assign a date to them.
- Iterate through the chunks - if you get to a call too early, discard that permutation.  Otherwise add or subtract points based on whether the call was made before the end date.  Store the total score as the score for that permutation.
- Choose the permutation with the highest score.

Comment: i dont know about that... generate every permutation of a 6000 (expected number of calls on the first week) calls backlog looks very very expensive and not very "dynamic"...

Comment: @Leonardo - That's why it's the "Brute force" solution.  It doesn't scale well, but it works for small enough data sets.  Even if you don't use it for your live code, you might want to implement it for a small test set of data in order to cross-check your algorithm.